# Why Clang running on Windows has no C conformance (__STDC__ is not defined to 1)?

Tags: c, clang, c11, standards-compliance, c17

Sample code (t127.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ret;
#if __STDC__ == 1
    printf("Has C conformance to version ");
#if __STDC_VERSION__
    printf("%ld", __STDC_VERSION__);
#else
    printf("1989");
#endif
    printf(" OR has no C conformance but __STDC__ is defined to 1\n");
    ret = 0;
#else
    printf("Has no C conformance\n");
    ret = 1;
#endif
    return ret;
}
```

Invocation:

```
$ clang t127.c -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic && ./a.exe
Has no C conformance

# comparison with gcc
$ gcc t127.c -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic && ./a.exe
Has C conformance to version 201112 OR has no C conformance but __STDC__ is defined to 1

$ clang --version
clang version 11.0.1
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ systeminfo
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041
```

Questions:

1. Why Clang running on Windows has no C conformance (`__STDC__` is not defined to 1)? I.e. what are the (technical) obstacles, which prevent "Clang running on Windows" to define `__STDC__` to 1?
2. Which extra options need to be specified to make Clang C conformant on Windows?

Comment: works fine for me, target `x86_64-w64-windows-gnu`  . Sounds like you are using a non-conforming build, perhaps you could file a report with wherever you got this build from

Comment: Perhaps for compatibility with MSVC (since you ar eusing `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160 where it is defined only when extensions are disabled.  What happens if you change the test to `#if __STDC__ == 1 || defined __STDC_VERSION__`?

Comment: MSVC may be non-conforming. ;-)

Comment: Maybe they drop STDC on purpose when using MS CRT and libs? Since those aren't conforming to the standard.

Comment: Btw I think `__STDC__` and `__STDC_VERSION__` were introduced in "C95", the technical corrigendum of C89. So C89 implementations may or may not have them, depending on if they implemented C95 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the definition of `__STDC__` depends on clang's distribution.

@M.M

> works fine for me, target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu . Sounds like you are using a non-conforming build, perhaps you could file a report with wherever you got this build from

Thanks for the confirmation an for the idea.

In the test above `clang version 11.0.1` was used. It was obtained from `LLVM-11.0.1-win64.exe`, which is shipped at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-11.0.1.

In comparison clang installed via [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) installer (`setup-x86_64.exe`) shows C conformance:

```
$ clang t127.c -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic && ./a.exe
Has C conformance to version 201112 OR has no C conformance but __STDC__ is defined to 1

$ clang --version
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus
Thread model: posix
```

@Clifford

> What happens if you change the test to #if **STDC** == 1 || defined **STDC_VERSION**?

```
#if __STDC__ == 1 || defined __STDC_VERSION__
```

Invocation:

```
$ /cygdrive/d/LLVM/11.0.1/bin/clang t127.c -std=gnu11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic && ./a.exe
Has C conformance to version 201112 OR has no C conformance but __STDC__ is defined to 1
```

So, by some (what?) reason `clang version 11.0.1` from `LLVM-11.0.1-win64.exe` does not define `__STDC__` to 1.